# Windows 10 "snap" features no longer work with shortcuts after major update

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-upgrade, aero-snap, windows-snap-assist

After the recent major Windows 10 update after the notification that support for earlier Windows 10 base versions will cease in November, "snap" features stopped working with keyboard shortcuts.

All snap settings set to "enabled".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMGt3.png

"Snap" still works when using the edge of the screen.

However, when using Win+Arrow the following features no longer work (simple snap to the side still does - the others do not):

- no longer resizes adjacent windows & the "connecting border" between windows is missing
- no longer opens the prompt with suggestions for selecting adjacent windows
- doesn't allow for placing windows in 1/4 (corner) of the screen  (Win+Right+Down) and the down arrow instead simply minimizes the window

Comment: What have you tried to do to remedy the issue?
[Just for fun](https://i1.wp.com/www.itro.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Have-you-tried-turning-it-off-and-on-again.png?fit=600%2C317&ssl=1)